# Why can I not assign a passed in object to a new value in a method?

Tags: java, methods

The code in Java:

```
private BiNode root = null;

//constructor
BST(int[] r) {
    BiNode s = new BiNode(r[0], null, null);
    test(root, s);
}

private  void test(BiNode head, BiNode s){
    head = s;

    if (head != null)
        System.out.println("head is not null");
    if (root == null)
        System.out.println("root is null");
}
```

Output:

```
head is not null
root is null
```

Why does `root` not equal `head` in the `test` method?

Comment: You never set `root` equal to anything. Research pass by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `root` in the constructor to the method `test`, the method actually uses a new pointer to the object's value, which is null (`root`'s value). So in the method when you change the value of `head` to `s` you are not making any changes to `root`'s pointer, which remains as null, but `head`´s value changes.

This is a java hindrance, which is you cannot pass pointers, and nothing you can do in java will get around this, so you have to set `root` directly.

Comment: I get your point. If I want to change 'root' in 'test', I should first initiate : 'root = new BiNode(); '. Is it right?

Comment: No, even initiating it won't change a thing. You have to assign it directly, so you have to put 'root = something;'. You could make an object that has a `root` field, then pass that object to a method and change that object's field to whatever you want, but this would require some time to elaborate, and I don't see what's your goal here :)